# can't set config #1, error -32

Tags: drivers, usb

It is unknown why some USB device can't work, we can see the related log as follows:

```
Aug 14 16:47:31 antec kernel: [382974.722605] usb 1-1.5: new full-speed USB device number 3 using ehci-pci
Aug 14 16:47:36 antec kernel: [382979.808654] usb 1-1.5: New USB device found, idVendor=04b0, idProduct=0114
Aug 14 16:47:36 antec kernel: [382979.808658] usb 1-1.5: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
Aug 14 16:47:36 antec kernel: [382979.808660] usb 1-1.5: Product: NIKON DSC E3100
Aug 14 16:47:36 antec kernel: [382979.809402] usb 1-1.5: can't set config #1, error -32
```

Google got many results but seems no answer.

Is that a cable issue or driver issue?

Here the examples:

https://forum.hddguru.com/viewtopic.php?f=1&t=32960&mobile=mobile
https://bugzilla.redhat.com/show_bug.cgi?id=997198

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely a driver issue. I've seen a Huion tablet working fine on the same hardware in Windows 10 but failing with this error on Debian.